# using javascript for format html string

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I need format html string. Just like in some html editor (Netbean with Alt-Shift-F). Anyone know any js function or lib can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this migth help you [code-pretiffy](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)